# Python sqlite3 error- the database is encrypted

Tags: sql, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to query a data base in the form of an SQL file I have downloaded on my computer to use the data in a machine learning project.  I've looked at the database source code, and there is no password setting statement, so I'm very confused at the error I keep getting, which is 'DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database.'

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con  = None
con = lite.connect('haiku1aip1.sql')
cur =  con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM haiku1aip1')
rows = cur.fetchall()
poems = []
for row in rows:
    poems.append(row)
print(poems)
```

Comment: Is haiku1aip1.sql a sqlite database or something else (like a text file full of SQL statements)?

Answer (score 1):

`con = lite.connect('haiku1aip1.sql')`

This line is trying to connect to a database named "haiku1aip1.sql", but `.sql` is not the correct file extension for a database file. Your database file would end in `.db`.

`.sql` files contain SQL queries, inserts, and other statements (similar to your `"SELECT * FROM haiku1aip1"` query).

Comment: So would the solution be to create the data base from the file of sql commands I have, and then to access it with this code, with the exception of changing the file extension like you mentioned?

Comment: @anonymous_duck It depends on what statements are inside the SQL file. Is it queries (eg. `SELECT ...`)? Or does it also create tables or insert data (eg. `CREATE ...`, `INSERT ...`)?